# Does the Pyromancer sorcerer's Fiery Soul feature totally bypass immunity to fire damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, damage-resistance, immunities

The [Pyromancer](https://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/magic/Plane-Shift_Kaladesh.pdf#page=9) sorcerous origin from [*Plane Shift: Kaladesh*](https://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/magic/Plane-Shift_Kaladesh.pdf) has a feature called Fiery Soul:

> At 18th level, you gain immunity to fire damage. In addition, any spell or effect you create ignores resistance to fire damage and treats immunity to fire damage as resistance to fire damage.

This ability allows you to treat immunity to fire damage as resistance to fire damage... and allows you to ignore resistance to fire damage.

Does the "ignore resistance" portion of this feature allow you to also ignore immunity that is turned into resistance by this feature?

Note: This is not *official* D&D 5e source material. Rather, it is something like Wizards of the Coast's "official homebrew"; it's un-playtested material by James Wyatt.

Comment: Related question about the interaction between Fiery Soul and Elemental Adept: [Does the Pyromancer sorcerer's Fiery Soul feature work with the Elemental Adept feat (fire damage) to effectively ignore immunity as well?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174982/does-the-pyromancer-sorcerers-fiery-soul-feature-work-with-the-elemental-adept)

Comment: Highly related (possible duplicate?) on [Does Ring of Earth Elemental Command allow passage through Solid Earth/Rock at normal terrain pace?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96745)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### No, it doesn't completely bypass immunity

When a feature is designed to ignore both immunity and resistance to a damage type, rather than "reduce/step down" one level of protection, it is quite explicit in this. One other class feature does this - the [School of Evocation wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofEvocation)'s [Overchannel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#Overchannel-439) feature:

> [...] Each time you use this feature again before finishing a long rest, the necrotic damage per spell level increases by 1d12. **This damage ignores resistance and immunity.**

Here, the ability is clear that it ignores both immunity and resistance because it groups them together. In contrast, the Pyromancer's Fiery Soul breaks each step down and separates them, indicating that it only works to either change immunity into resistance *or* change resistance into regular damage.

Answer (score 11):

### No

Although the text is somewhat unclear, the lack of clarity points to the answer.

If the intention was for all immunity to be bypassed, it would be written something like

> At 18th level, you gain immunity to fire damage. In addition, any spell or effect you create ignores resistance and immunity to fire damage

Instead, the text simply downgrades immunity to resistance, and any previous resistance is ignored.

Answer (score 4):

## The wording leaves a lot open to interpretation

There are two ways to read this ability:

1. Creatures with fire resistance are treated as having no resistance, and creatures with fire immunity are treated as having fire resistance. Essentially going down only one step in either case.
2. Fire resistance is ignored. Since immunity is treated as resistance, it is also ignored.

Due to what I see as ambiguous writing, either interpretation could be derived from the ability and it would be up to the DM to have the final say in how this ability works in their game.

It would seem to me that the intent here is for it to be treated as case 1, causing fire resistance/immunity to move down one step. If it were intended to cause both fire resistance *and* immunity to be ignored, it could have easily said so in fewer words.

Answer (score 1):

#### It's open to interpretation.

However, it **does** allow your spells to do so, in conjunction with your 6th level feature, Fire in the Veins:

> At 6th level, you gain resistance to fire damage. In addition, **spells you cast ignore resistance to fire damage**.

(Emphasis mine.) Since this is a separate feature, there is no question that this can be applied to the 'result' of the Fiery Soul feature. As you quoted, the feature:

> treats immunity to fire damage as resistance

Since Fire in the Veins allows the Pyromancer to ignore resistance to fire damage with its spells, it will deal full damage to a creature with resistance or immunity to fire damage—but this is only definite with its spells.

As for whether the feature 'stacks with itself', this is a matter which will come down to the DM you're playing with, regardless of your reading. Linguistically, you ignore resistance [to fire damage] ***and*** treat immunity as resistance. There's no 'instead' or 'alternatively', so if you read the rules literally, it seems the answer to your question is yes.

One final thing to note is that this feature **leaves no space for choice and makes no distinctions**: if you take the above interpretation, you **will** also ignore ***your own*** resistance and immunity to fire damage—even that provided by the same feature.